# GIT: How to rename a file but keep its history?

Tags: git

My project has several bad named files. I want to rename them. I tried to use:

```
 git mv nameA nameB
 git commit
```

After rename, I found that I must use:

```
 git log --follow nameB
```

To view history of the file. And `git blame nameB` lost original information of every line, now every line has the last commit id.

I wonder if there is a method to rename a file but keep all history of the file, including `git log` and `git blame`.

Comment: Git keeps all the history of every file, but it doesn't track renames directly. What command *doesn't* show the output you think it should? For me, if I test this out in a small repo, `git blame` shows the history, even across renames.

Comment: I tried the `git blame` command in a small repository, it could generate the right information without any options. Every line has their original commit id and original file name. Which version do you use? Can you show some more information? e.g., what's wrong with your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there is a similar problem with you, the user could not get the right output using `git blame` command. Then he tried

```
git blame -C -C filename
```

and get the right output.

I think you might want to take a look at this discussion. [git blame --follow](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-blame-follow-td6173253.html) .
Hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you really want to change the file name in the whole history, i.e. it should look like the file never had that bad name.

In this case you can use something like:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git mv oldname newname' -- --all
```

Be aware that `git filter-branch` is a very powerful tool. Be sure you have a backup of your repository in case you really break something. Also be aware that this is probably a bad idea if you already published your repository. There might also be some logical references to the old name in other files, which might render old commits unbuildable.

If you already published your repository, you probably should do a simple `git mv`, live with the bad name in your history and use the rename detection mechanism of git as shown in the other answer.

Comment: I get this error: `Rewrite c8d918bc05305bd80eba68b785112110767b9757 (1/1429)fatal: bad source, source=build, destination=tools
tree filter failed: git mv build tools
rm: cannot remove `d:/src/temp2/.git-rewrite/revs': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `d:/src/temp2/.git-rewrite': Directory not empty.` Any idea??